Mounting a Windows share on MacOS Sequoia
How do I mount a Windows server file share in MacOS in python?
An error results from this code (MacOS Sequoia, Windows Server 2022, VSCode, python 3.12.6):
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

remote_share = '//user:password@10.0.0.100/remote_share_folder'
local_folder = 'local_folder'

@contextmanager
def mounted():
    retcode = subprocess.call(['/sbin/mount_smbfs',  remote_share, local_folder])
    if retcode != 0:
        raise OSError("mount operation failed")

try:
    with mounted():
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(remote_share, 'textfile.txt'), local_folder)
except OSError as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")


Error: mount operation failed
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host


This is not a Python issue

Looks like smbclient is a painless way to transfer files from a Windows Server to a local Mac:
import smbclient

file_name = "mytext.txt"
remote_path = r"\\10.0.0.100\\shared_folder\\"
remotefile_path = fr"{remote_path}{file_name}"
local_path = "/Users/user/Documents/data/"
localfile_path = f"{local_path}{file_name}"

username = 'user'
pw = 'mypassword'

smbclient.ClientConfig(username=username, password=pw)

with smbclient.open_file(remotefile_path, mode="rb") as remote_file:
    content = remote_file.read()

with open(localfile_path, "wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(content)

# Write to a file
# with smbclient.open_file(remote_path, mode="w") as file:
#     file.write("Hello, Windows share!")

# List directory contents
# files = smbclient.listdir(remote_path)
# for file in files:
#     print(file)


This does not answer the question which is, effectively, "Why does /sbin/mount_smbfs fail?"
